# One login using flask

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-security

I have a flask app with a login page and connected to MySql. I usually run it on my localhost using chrome. My login's works fine. Now what i want is if i login into my app on a chrome it works fine simultaneously when i opened my app in another browser it gives again a login page which i don't need it.
I need only one login. If i logged in using chrome and if i open it in FireFox it should give me the logged in session not the corresponding login page.or just simply notify me "You are already logged in another browser, Log-out there and login Here.

Is this possible if so suggest me some steps.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely not possible, since one browser does not know anything about stored cookies in another.

The common approach is to force logout on another login attempt, or, as an option, login denial if user already logged in.

Another way would be to detect logged in users in by their IP address, but this is really bad idea, since there might be thousands of users behind a single IP.

Comment: Fine,
Then how to implement force logout on another login attempt, or, as an option, login denial if user already logged in.??

Comment: Sorry, but this community is about solving the problems, not about writing the code. Try implementing by yourself, come back with a programming-related question if you have a problem, and peeps will try to help you out.

Comment: I did not ask any code i need some guidance. Mr.Andrejs Cainikovs